# работа типа boolean

Tags: java

Значение переменой типа boolean по умолчанию false, но в консоль выводится "AD", почему так происходит ?

```
public class Main {
 public static void main (String[] args) {
    boolean x;
    if (x = true) System.out.print("A");
    else
        if (x) System.out.print("B");
     if(!x) System.out.print("C");
     else System.out.print("D");
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Потому что присваивание и сравнение - это разные операции.

Comment: окей,  а почему мы не заходим не в один из этих if:
`if (x) System.out.print("B");
        if(!x) System.out.print("C");`

Comment: Если бы у вас были правильно расставлены отступы, ответ был бы очевиден.

Comment: В if(!x) заходит.

Answer (score 2):

Исправьте  эту строку:
 `if (x = true) System.out.print("A");` 
на эту:
 `if (x == true) System.out.print("A");`.

== проверяет равна ли переменная x, true. А вот = присваивает переменной x значение true